# Xamarin Image source binding Fallback to a Model in a Listview

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have 1 Image but it should be able to receive one of 2 binding paths in a Listview

```xml
 <Label  x:Name="something" Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150"
                                            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                                            Source="{Binding images[0].src, }">

                                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

The product is one of 2 types single or Multi

If its multi the Binding changes from

```xml
 Source="{Binding images[0].src }">
```

To

```xml
 Source="{Binding image.src }">
```

*Note: I'm using a API wrapper so my Models are kind of Preset*
I see the docs mention Fallbacks cant have a binding

Any Solutions to this

Comment: You might want to use a value converter for this and convert these values based on some flags!! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the logic when your data come back from API:

Let's assume if you get data from API like a single model, you can :

```
    myModel model = new myModel() { name = "test", type = "single" , image = new myImage() { src ="myUrl"} };

    if (model.type is "single")
    {
        model.imageUrl = model.image.src;
    }
    else
    {
        model.imageUrl = model.images[0].src;
    }
```

if you get data from API like a ObservableCollection, you can :

```
    ObservableCollection<myModel> itemModels = new ObservableCollection<myModel>();
    itemModels.Add(new myModel() { name = "test", type = "single", image = new myImage() { src = "myUrl" } });
    itemModels.Add(new myModel() { name = "test", type = "Multi", image = new myImage() { src = "myUrl" } , images = new List<myImage> { new myImage() { src = "url"} } });

    foreach (myModel item in itemModels)
    {
        if (item.type is "single")
        {
            item.imageUrl = model.image.src;
        }
        else
        {
            item.imageUrl = model.images[0].src;
        }
    }
```

Then in the xaml, bind to `imageUrl`:

```
    <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150"
                                        DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                                        Source="{Binding imageUrl}">

    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

Here is some model I created for test:

```
public class myModel {

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string type { get; set; }

    public string imageUrl { get; set; }

    public List<myImage> images { get; set; }
    public myImage image;
}

public class myImage {
    public string src { get; set; }

}
```